# CreateGlobalApplicationCommandAsync not building slash commands

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have a discord.net bot trying to make slash commands, but the global commands don't add when I run the bot, I understand it takes a while to register, but it has been 2 days since it last registered for new commands

I tried:

```
_SlashCommandBuilder = new SlashCommandBuilder();
_SlashCommandBuilder.WithName("greet");
```

I expected: For it to add the build, I also did `await _DiscordClient.CreateGlobalApplicationCommandAsync(_SlashCommandBuilder.Build());`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use `.AddOption` and `.AddDescription` for it to correctly work, it all seems to work now.